# Is random access allowed in the Bit Complexity model, or is it just expensive?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, computation-models

In the [RAM model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), you're allowed to do unbounded indirect access (pointers can be arbitrarily large and still fit in a single machine word).

In the Bit Complexity model (no wiki article, sorry), machine words are constant sized. So storing the address of an entry in a table of size $N$ would require $O(lg(N))$ words.

This raises the question: Are you even *allowed* to do a multi-word random access into a table of size $N$ when using the bit complexity model? It's a bit of a strange operation, because the machine can't "hold the jump in its head" while making it. On the other hand, it could be allowed but cost $O(lg(n))$ time instead of the RAM model's $O(1)$ time.

I realize that this is basically just a definition, with interesting things on either side, but I'm wondering what the *common* definition is. Is bit complexity just another way of saying "multi-tape turing machine"?

Comment: Why do you say "instead of $O(1)$ time"?  Why would a multi-word random access be $O(1)$ time, when (if I understand you correctly) you said that a single-word random access takes $O(\lg N)$ time?

Comment: Where do you get that $O(\log(n))$ limit from in your first sentence? There is no such limit described in the linked WP article, nor have I seen such a limit in other definitions of RAM.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at this: http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~diem/preprints/bitcomplexity.pdf.

Comment: @D.W. I was contrasting it against the RAM model, where getting to items in a similarly sized table was cheap because the addresses fit into a word.

Comment: @FrankW It was a misunderstanding between the size of allowed arithmetic and the size of allowed pointers. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Fürer's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.1811.pdf), the underlying complexity model is a Turing machine without random access, or equivalently, Boolean circuits. So no random access is allowed. Check also [Diem's writeup](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~diem/preprints/bitcomplexity.pdf) on the subject.

Comment: Another source which is very careful regarding the model is the very recent http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3360v1.pdf, which proves a Fürer-type bound for integer multiplication with a simpler algorithm (and better constants).